# sqlalchemy cx_oracle cannot get results

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, cx-oracle

sqlalchemy+cx_Oracle may not be in your domain. 
However, if you can help me giving few web links/helps will be nice.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import MetaData
from sqlalchemy import Table
import cx_Oracle

engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://user:passwd@FTSDBLAB')
meta = MetaData()
meta.reflect(bind=engine)
tbl_mgr_theater = Table('mgr_table', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

connection = engine.connect()
result = connection.execute(tbl_mgr_theater.select())

print(result.rowcount())
```

### gives the following ERROR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
Error closing cursor
Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'cx_Oracle.Cursor' object has no attribute 'lastrowid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, rowcount is an *attribute*, so you sould use in this way:

```
print(result.rowcount)
```

But it will return 0. **Why**?

Because is only useful in an **UPDATE** or **DELETE** statement. Contrary to what the Python DBAPI says, it does not return the number of rows available from the results of a **SELECT** statement as DBAPIs cannot support this functionality when rows are unbuffered.

How can I get the rowcount of a **SELECT** statement?

You can **SELECT** with **COUNT** in this way:

```
result = connection.execute(tbl_mgr_theater.select().count())
```

It will return a ResultProxy. But if you want an int result, you could do:

```
result=[x for x in connection.execute(tbl_mgr_theater.select().count())][0][0]
```

As you know is a **SELECT COUNT** statement (it will only return one field), you could set the first **[0]**, the second is to parse the RowProxy to int.

Hope it helps you.